# Dynamic Tab content rendering

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm developing tabs component and I want Angular to render and initialize only active tab instead of all tabs. How can it be done?

```
<my-tabs>
  <my-tab [tabTitle]="'Tab1'">
    <some-component></some-component>
  </my-tab>
  <my-tab [tabTitle]="'Tab2'">
    <some-component2></some-component2>
</my-tabs>
```

Basicaly In this case the first tub is active, so `<some-component></some-component>` should be initialized, but `<some-component2></some-component2>` shouldn't as Tab2 is not active

Answer (score 0):

Use `*ngIf` on the component. When the value if false, the component will be removed from the DOM, and therefore not initialised. Something roughly like:

```
  <my-tab [tabTitle]="'Tab1'">
    <some-component *ngIf="tabOneActive" ></some-component>
  </my-tab>
```

Comment: I was wondering if it's possible to do inside of the tubs component.

Comment: If you do it in the tabs and not the component then the tab you don't select won't exist as a tab on the page.